# Using custom ellipsis for truncated text in Tabulator

Tags: tabulator

I use Tabulator component and I need replace regular ellipsis (...) with custom.
Then I want add click event for them. Main idea - user can click on custom ellipsis (or glyph) and for him will be shown modal window with full text and a copy button.

Most browsers don`t support custom string as ellipsis, so I cant use CSS property.

I think I can add some glyph using Tabulator formatter functionality and handle click on this glyph, but in this case I got another problem: "how check text is truncated".

Please give advice with this - custom ellipsis in Tabulator cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use a [Custom Formatter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/format) to achieve this.

because formatter functions are called before the element is added to the DOM you will need to use the onRendered callback passed into the function to trigger the display of the ellipsis if the cell is overflowing once it is drawn:

```
//custom formatter
var ellipsisFormatter = function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){
    onRendered(function(){
        var element = cell.getElement();

        if(element.scrollWidth > element.clientWidth){
            //add ellipsis
        }else{
            //hide ellipsis
        }
    });

    return cell.getValue();
});

//column definition
{title:"Name", field:"name", formatter:ellipsisFormatter},
```

Comment: Hello, and thank you a lot!
I`m novice in JS and totally missed onRendered callback ability.

PS I use your sample with changed (typo) e.scrollWidth -> element.scrollWidth

Comment: If you are happy with this answer, would you mind marking it as the answer so others know it is worth using